# Why is Gunicorn necessary to make Django work with nginx?

Tags: nginx, python, django, gunicorn

Why does Django need a server like Gunicorn to work with NGINx? Why is nginx not enough?

Answer (score 1):

It is required because nginx is not a python WSGI interpreter. You could ask the same question about Rails or PHP, both of which also require application-specific software that works in conjunction with nginx.